# How do I seperate pixel-events when I have 2 pixels installed on my website through Google tag manager?

Tags: facebook, google-tag-manager, pixel

I have two pixels on my website, one for B2B and one for B2C, and both are implemented via Google Tag Manager. 
I´m new on working with the pixel and I was wondering how I can seperate the events that i´m creating trough GTM?

When I use fbq in a custom HTML tag does this send hits to both of the pixels interface?

I have two different purchase-flow, one for b2b and one for b2c, and i dont want too send b2b purchase data to the b2c facebook business interface!

Is there a way of seperating them so the correct data ends up in the correct facebook pixels interface?

I have no idea if fbq("trackSingle", ...) works through Google tag manager?

This is the set up in GTM:

```
 <!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
  !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
  {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
  n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
  if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
  n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
  t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
  'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
  fbq('init', '**1ST_PIXEL_CODE**');
  fbq('init', '**2ND_PIXEL_CODE**');
  fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
  src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=1ST_PIXEL_CODE&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/>
  <img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=2ND_PIXEL_CODE&ev=PageView&noscript=1"/>
</noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code —>
```

Comment: Why should it _not_ work? Why don’t you _try_ it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a picture up of the configuration of the custom html tag?